# (Godot 4.0 Engine) How to execute code after window resizing and mouse button releasing only

Tags: input, window, godot, gdscript

---

By using Godot 4.0, how to execute some code after the main OS window has been resized and the left mouse button has been released?

---

The reason behind this question is that I need to execute a performance-heavy method after the screen has been resized but not continuously while it's resizing.

By using the `Viewport` `size_changed` signal or the notification `NOTIFICATION_WM_SIZE_CHANGED`, the callbacks are called every time the screen has been changed even if the left mouse button is still pressed on the window's edge.

I have tried to detect the `pressed` state of the left mouse button in the `_process` method, but the engine cannot listen to events outside it's window / viewport as far as I know.

Thank you,

Answer (score 2):

As a simple yet effective workaround, (re)start a one-shot timer in the `size_changed` handler, with a `wait_time` of something like 0.25 sec (or even more). As long as the user is dragging the window border, the timer will be reset and your performance-heavy method be postponed until dragging has stopped for the given `wait_time`.

Add a `Timer` node named `ViewPortResizeTimer` to your root node (or create it in code). Set its `one_shot` property to `true` and set its `wait_time` to 0.25 sec. Connect its `timeout()` signal to a method in your script.

Script of your root node:

```py
func _ready():
    get_viewport().connect("size_changed", _on_viewport_resize)

func _on_viewport_resize():
    # Starts the timer or resets its time_left if already running.
    ($ViewPortResizeTimer as Timer).start()

func _on_view_port_resize_timer_timeout():
    print("viewport size has stabilized - do performance-heavy stuff")
```

Comment: Indeed, with this method the frequent calls on window resize are only delayed. The longer the wait time is, the slower the user will see the results regardless of when the user has finished with the window resizing. Except, only if I also connect the mouse_entered signal and execute the function from there too and stop the timer in the process if it's still active.

Answer (score 1):

There is no native way to do that, because as you said, the engine does not listen to events outside of the window.

There is however, signals on the Window object to notify you of when the mouse enters or exists.

When you start the resize, the mouse is considered outside of the window (and the signal `Window.mouse_exited()` is emitted, but you don't need it here).

But at some point you will probably get the mouse back in the window, which will then trigger the `Window.mouse_entered()` signal.

You can mix that with the `size_changed` signal to achieve something that's close to what you need.

Here is an example that I got working

```
extends Node2D

var got_resized : bool = false

func _ready() -> void:
    get_viewport().connect("size_changed", _on_viewport_resize)
    get_viewport().get_window().connect("mouse_entered", _on_mouse_in)

func _on_viewport_resize():
    got_resized = true
    # 
func _on_mouse_in():
    if (got_resized):
        # Run your heavy code here
        print("This is executed only after a resize, and when the mouse gets back in the window")
        
        # Then switch the flag back off.
        got_resized = false
```

This does not however execute on mouse release, but when the mouse gets back inside the window.

Cheers

Comment: Unfortunately, this method will not work properly if the screen is maximized. The mouse_entered signal will not be triggered unless the user has to move the cursor in and out of the screen for the updates to take place.

Comment: How do you maximize the screen? With this script, works as-is when I click the maximize button, or when I double click the window bar. It executes the code only once as expected. It works for the same reason, when you maximize using either one of those 2 methods, the screen is considered ouside of the screen. Give it a shot, it might be what you need.